# Only return rows after the exists condtion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an SQL server Query

This returns orders from customers of products that are related / added to their OrderID (Final Invoice)

This uses an exists condition

```
Select * from Orders o1
where DepartmentSpecialty = 'LivingRoom'
and Exists (SELECT o2.Department  FROM Orders o2    WHERE o2.Department = 'Kitchen' 
    and o1.ID = o2.ID
    and o1.OrderID = o2.OrderID
)
```

I only wish to bring back rows for the order dates *AFTER* they have ordered from the Kitchen Department in relation to their OrderID. This whom ordered from the Living Room department.

Any ideas team that I can amend the SQL to do this  please

Comment: Provide some table structure

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?that really help

Comment: On a side note, can I suggest working on a better naming scheme. A table called `Orders` that contains *both* an `ID` column and an `OrderID` column would confuse a great many people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without a `join` or subquery, by using window functions:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             min(case when o.Department = 'Kitchen'
                      then date
                 end) over (partition by id, orderid) as kitchen_date
      from orders o
     ) o
where o.DepartmentSpecialty = 'LivingRoom' and
      o.date > o.kitchen_date;
```

I suspect that your original `join` conditions (and hence the `partition by` columns) are too restrictive.  I would expect these to be some sort of customer id.

Comment: Hi thank you , this worked a treat. Thanks team x needed a distinct however by the first o.*

Answer (score 0):

something a bit like this perhaps

```
Select * from Orders o1

where DepartmentSpecialty = 'LivingRoom'

and o1.orderdate >= (SELECT MIN(o2.orderdate) FROM Orders o2    WHERE o2.Department = 'Kitchen' 

and o1.ID = o2.ID
and o1.OrderID = o2.OrderID)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT o1.*
FROM Orders AS o1
    INNER JOIN Orders AS o2 
        ON o1.OrderId = o2.OrderId
        AND o1.[SomeDateField] > o2.[SomeDateField] -- You will need to specify a date field
WHERE o1.DepartmentSpecialty = 'LivingRoom'  -- Department Your interested in
AND o2.DepartmentSpeciality = 'Kitchen' -- Inital Department
```